# Lisp list linearization with map

Tags: lisp, map-function

Is it possible to linearize a list using a map functions?

Example: (1 2 (3 (4 5) 6)) -> (1 2 3 4 5 6)

My wrong approach:

```
(defun f1 (x)
    (cond
        ((atom x) x)
        (t (f2 x))
    )
)

(defun f2 (lst)
    (mapcar 'f1 lst)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, map, though not `mapcar` but `mapcan`:

```
(defun flatten (lst)
  (mapcan
     #'(lambda (a)
         (cond
           ((atom a) (list a))
           (T (flatten a))))
     lst))
```

And if by Lisp you meant Scheme or something like it, try `append-map`, `flat-map`, `flatMap` or `mapcat` instead of the Common Lisp's `mapcan`.

Comment: Wow! [*This* muLisp](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/SdAoltVEJZo)? TIL.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this `linearize a list` but **flatten the list**.

```
(defun flatten (lst)
"Flatten the list lst"
  (cond ((null lst) nil)
        ((atom lst) (list lst))
        (t (loop for e in lst appending (flatten e)))))
```